# Removing certificate from storage does not work

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm trying to remove certificate from storage and using this function:

```
    public static void RemoveFromStorage(StoreName storeName, IEnumerable<CertInfo> certificates)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed | OpenFlags.IncludeArchived);

        foreach (var cert in certificates)
        {
            var toRemove = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cert.Thumbprint, false);
            store.Certificates.Remove(toRemove[0]);
        }

        store.Close();
    }
```

Function doesn't throw any exception, Find function returns proper certificate from storage, but after calling Remove function it is not removed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line

```
store.Certificates.Remove(toRemove[0]);
```

Correct is:

```
store.Remove(toRemove[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The store needs to be opened for ReadWrite.

Try this:

```
public static void RemoveFromStorage(StoreName storeName, IEnumerable<CertInfo>    certificates)
{
    var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed | OpenFlags.IncludeArchived | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    foreach (var cert in certificates)
    {
        var toRemove = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cert.Thumbprint, false);
        store.Certificates.Remove(toRemove[0]);
    }

    store.Close();
}
```